# Can I assign a value to a string using ternary operator in C?

Tags: c, string, initialization, ternary-operator

I need to assign the string to `a` and then print it using `%s`. If I run the following code, I get an error message saying `Invalid Initializer`. Is there a way to do it correctly without using `switch/case` or `if/else`?

```
char a[25] = ((ws < 1) ? "Calm" : 
              (ws >= 1) && ws < 4) ? "Light Air" :
              (ws >= 4 && ws <= 27) ? "Breeze" :
              (ws >= 28 && ws <= 47) ? "Gale": 
              (ws >= 48 && ws <= 63) ? "Storm" : "Hurricane");
```

Comment: No. The initializer has to be a constant. And for this question you should have simplified the expression. And I would suggest to do the same for your own code as well.

Comment: and why you would like to write a code as above anyway? You ever think of the person who's going to maintain this code? What if there are some more conditions to be added in future?

Comment: Maintainable solution: Use a header file to define the target strings, then based on the condition, either assign them or `strcpy()` them.

Comment: You cannot assign a value to a string at all. A string is a character array. You cannot assign to arrays. Initialisation is not assignment. You can try using a pointer instead: `const char* a = ...`

Comment: @n.m. Although O.P describes the problem as _assignment_.  Code is attempting  _initialization_ - something that can be done with `char a[25]  = "Calm";`

Comment: @EugeneSh. Re: "No. The initializer has to be a constant."  Is not `char ws = rand();
  char b[25] = {ws, ws};` a valid, not-constant initialization?

Comment: @chux Are you saying that the OPs code should be working?

Comment: @EugeneSh. no, but the reason is not that the initializer has to be a constant, because it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @n.m., chux Please explain the difference, I understand what you are saying, but can't tell the formal reason.

Comment: The formal reason is that the initialiser is an expression, which is not suitable as an initialiser for a variable of type `char[25]`. It requires a braced initialiser list or a string literal.

Answer (score 1):

"I need to assign the string to a and then print it using %s."

You're not doing assignment but initialization. No, you cannot use an expression to initialize an entire array, this is due to unfortunate legacy reasons.

Also, arrays are not even assignable. No, it is not possible to do this. However since you just need to print it using `"%s"`, you can use a *pointer to `char`*.

```
char *a = ((ws < 1) ? "Calm" : 
           (ws >= 1) && ws < 4) ? "Light Air" :
           (ws >= 4 && ws <= 27) ? "Breeze" :
           (ws >= 28 && ws <= 47) ? "Gale": 
           (ws >= 48 && ws <= 63) ? "Storm" : "Hurricane");

printf("Wind level: %s\n", a);
```